# Pass Date as parameter in DAO and Servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

This is in relation with my recent question...

In this situation I have my DAO and servlet, now I want to pass the date (event_date) as parameter to my query. Where can I do that?

Part of my servlet

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    SimpleDateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD");

    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String dateto = request.getParameter("dateto");        


try
    {


        List prodlistsearch_array = this.pdtDAO.prodlistsearch(name);
        request.setAttribute("prodlistsearch_array", prodlistsearch_array);

        request.getRequestDispatcher("events_audit.jsp").forward(request, response);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      throw new ServletException("Cannot retrieve areas", e);
    }
```

Part of my DAO

```
public List<pdtBean> prodlistsearch(String name) throws SQLException{
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;


    String querystring = "select * from mydb where name = ? and event_date between ? and ?";
    List<pdtBean> prodlistsearch_array = new ArrayList<pdtBean>();

    try {

        connection = database.getConnection();
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(querystring);
                    statement.setString(1, name);

        resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

        while (resultSet.next()) {

            pdtBean prodlistsearcharray = new pdtBean();

                prodlistsearcharray.setId(resultSet.getString("id"));
                prodlistsearcharray.setEvent_date(resultSet.getString("event_date"));
                prodlistsearcharray.setTitle(resultSet.getString("title"));

            prodlistsearch_array.add(prodlistsearcharray);
        }
    } finally {
        try { resultSet.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
        try { statement.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
        try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
    }

    return prodlistsearch_array;

}
```

Comment: I really hope `try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}` is just a pseudo-code!

Answer (score 0):

A very simple workaround is to pass another argument type of `java.util.Date` to your DAO method. But, I would suggest to create a `POJO` (A Java Bean with getter and setter in simple terms) and set properties using the parameters received.

Pass the object to `DAO` method, this will be helpful if you need some more constraints.